# Android ICS context menu replacement

Tags: android

I'm looking for information on what seems to be the replacement for long press menus starting with ICS.

If you have the latest version of Google Music, you can see the menu, it's attached to pretty much anything and it's a little right triangle.

Since long press context menus are now discouraged and context menu are not re-created on larger screens, I am looking to implement these ICS menus.  I am looking for either a view that has this behavior or specifications on this icon, its spacing, its size, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the widget, it's actually a spinner.  The source code for the "email" application has a sample that we can see here:

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/master/res/layout/account_setup_incoming_fragment.xml

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/account_setup_incoming_security_label"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/account_security_type"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/account_setup_incoming_security_label" />
```

If we look at this UI in the email program, we can see the little triangle menu and it's this spinner that is contributing it.

The little triangle icon can be found here:

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/master/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_mailbox_collapsed_holo_light.png

and some sample usage can be found here:

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/master/src/com/android/email/activity/MailboxFragmentAdapter.java